# NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm using locally hosted domains for dev purposes on Windows VM. For accessing https I'm using a self-signed SSL certificate generated by OpenSSL tool. I generate a certificate, add it to nginx.conf, add the key to Trusted Root Certification Authorities in VM. But Chrome returns me NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. As I understood it wants the certificate to have a subjectAltName record, but my efforts to put it in my certificate got me nothing. I'm doing it as Google & SO says, but it doesn't satisfy Chrome. What does it want me to do? Thanks!

Command (MacOS):

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ./selfsigned.key -out ./selfsigned.crt -subj '/CN=host.com/O=My Company Name LTD./C=US' -config ./ext3.conf
```

ext3.conf:

```
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = host.com
```